# jquery plugin multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm trying to create a simple jQuery plugin that allows for multiple instances of a "timepicker".  I haven't done much JavaScript OOP in the past so I figured that create this would be an excellent learning experience for me.  That being said, I cannot seem to figure out why all instances are affected when I changed the time.  This is my first post on StackOverflow so please bear with me.
Here's the code:

```js
(function($) {

  //Helper functions 
  if (typeof String.prototype.endsWith != 'function') {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function(str) {
      return str.length > 0 && this.substring(this.length - str.length, this.length) === str;
    }
  }

  //Find if area is on the clickable list
  var findOne = function(haystack, arr) {
    return arr.some(function(v) {
      return haystack.indexOf(v) >= 0;
    });
  };

  var Timepicker = function(element, options) {

    this.defaults = {
      now: new Date()
    };
    this.element = $(element);
    this.createTimepicker();
    this.options = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
    this.timepicker = $('.wicked-picker'); //The outer portion of the picker
    this.up = $('.wicked-picker__controls__control-up'); //the up control(s)
    this.down = $('.wicked-picker__controls__control-down'); //the down control(s)
    this.hoursElem = $('.wicked-picker__controls__control--hours'); //the hours text
    this.minutesElem = $('.wicked-picker__controls__control--minutes'); //the minutes text
    this.meridiemElem = $('.wicked-picker__controls__control--meridiem'); //the am or pm text
    this.canClick = ['timepicker', this.timepicker.selector.substring(1), this.up.selector.substring(1), this.down.selector.substring(1), this.hoursElem.selector.substring(1), this.minutesElem.selector.substring(1), this.meridiemElem.selector.substring(1)]; //the clickable areas
    this.selectedHour = ((this.defaults.now.getHours() + 11) % 12) + 1; //the default hour
    this.selectedMin = ((this.defaults.now.getMinutes() < 10) ? '0' : '') + this.defaults.now.getMinutes(); //the default minute
    this.selectedMeridiem = (this.defaults.now.getHours > 12) ? 'PM' : 'AM'; //the defaut meridiem
    this.attach(element); //attach events to this element

  };

  $.extend(Timepicker.prototype = {

    showTimepicker: function(element) {
      var timepickerPos = this.element.offset();
      //set time to default time (now)
      this.setText(element);
      //if the timepicker's time differs from the input field's time change it
      if (this.getText(element) !== this.getTime()) {
        var inputTime = this.getText(element).replace(':', '').split(' ');
        var newTime = new Date();
        newTime.setHours(inputTime[0]);
        newTime.setMinutes(inputTime[2]);
        this.setTime(newTime);
      }
      //Positioning
      this.timepicker.css({
        'z-index': this.element.zIndex() + 1,
        position: 'absolute',
        left: timepickerPos.left,
        top: timepickerPos.top + element.target.offsetHeight + 5
      }).show();

      //Time up/down events
      //Most likely the area with issues
      //Needs to know which instance
      $(this.up).on('click', $.proxy(this.changeValue, this, '+', element));
      $(this.down).on('click', $.proxy(this.changeValue, this, '-', element));
    },

    hideTimepicker: function(element) {
      var targetClass = element.target.className.split(' ');
      //Check if area is clickable before hiding
      if (findOne(targetClass, this.canClick) === false) {
        this.timepicker.hide();
      }
    },

    //Create only one timepicker per page
    createTimepicker: function() {
      if ($('.wicked-picker').length === 0)
        $('body').append('<div class="wicked-picker"> <p class="wicked-picker__title">Timepicker</p> <ul class="wicked-picker__controls"> <li class="wicked-picker__controls__control"> <span class="wicked-picker__controls__control-up"></span><span class="wicked-picker__controls__control--hours">00</span><span class="wicked-picker__controls__control-down"></span> </li> <li class="wicked-picker__controls__control"> <span class="wicked-picker__controls__control-up"></span><span class="wicked-picker__controls__control--minutes">00</span><span class="wicked-picker__controls__control-down"></span> </li> <li class="wicked-picker__controls__control"> <span class="wicked-picker__controls__control-up"></span><span class="wicked-picker__controls__control--meridiem">AM</span><span class="wicked-picker__controls__control-down"></span> </li> </ul> </div>');
    },

    //Attach the show and hide picker events
    attach: function(element) {
      $(element).on('focus', $.proxy(this.showTimepicker, this));
      $('body').on('click', $.proxy(this.hideTimepicker, this));
    },

    //set the timepicker's time 
    setTime: function(time) {
      this.setHours(time.getHours());
      this.setMinutes(time.getMinutes());
      this.setMeridiem();
    },

    //get the timepicker's time in the form H : MM : AM || PM
    getTime: function() {
      return [this.getHours + ' : ' + this.getMinutes() + ' ' + this.getMeridiem()];
    },

    //set the timepicker's and input field's hours
    setHours: function(hours) {
      var hour = new Date();
      hour.setHours(hours);
      var hoursText = ((hour.getHours() + 11) % 12) + 1;
      this.hoursElem.text(hoursText);
      this.selectedHour = hoursText;
    },

    //set the timepicker's hours
    getHours: function() {
      var hours = new Date();
      hours.setHours(this.hoursElem.text());
      return hours.getHours();
    },

    //set the timepicker's and input field's minutes
    setMinutes: function(minutes) {
      var minute = new Date();
      minute.setMinutes(minutes);
      var minutesText = minute.getMinutes();
      var min = ((minutesText < 10) ? '0' : '') + minutesText;
      this.minutesElem.text(min);
      this.selectedMin = min;
    },

    //set the timepicker's minutes
    getMinutes: function() {
      var minutes = new Date();
      minutes.setMinutes(this.minutesElem.text());
      var minutesText = minutes.getMinutes();
      return ((minutesText < 10) ? '0' : '') + minutesText;
    },

    //set the timepicker's and input field's meridiem
    setMeridiem: function() {
      var meridiem = this.getMeridiem();
      var newMeridiem = (meridiem === 'PM') ? 'AM' : 'PM';
      this.meridiemElem.text(newMeridiem);
      this.selectedMeridiem = newMeridiem;
    },

    //set the timepicker's meridiem
    getMeridiem: function() {
      return this.meridiemElem.text();
    },

    //change the input field's time based on the arrow selected for each time unit
    //input is the input field to be changed
    //element is the up or down arrow clicked
    //operator is the '+' or '-' sign
    changeValue: function(operator, input, element) {
      var target = (operator === '+') ? element.target.nextSibling : element.target.previousSibling;
      var targetClass = $(target).attr('class');
      if (targetClass.endsWith('hours')) {
        this.setHours(eval(this.getHours() + operator + 1));
      } else if (targetClass.endsWith('minutes')) {
        this.setMinutes(eval(this.getMinutes() + operator + 1));
      } else {
        this.setMeridiem();
      }
      console.log('changed ' + $(input.target).attr('name'));
      this.setText(input);
    },


    //Set the input field's time
    setText: function(input) {
      console.log('set ' + $(input.target).attr('name') + ' to ' + this.selectedHour + ' : ' + this.selectedMin + ' ' + this.selectedMeridiem);
      $(input.target).val(this.selectedHour + ' : ' + this.selectedMin + ' ' + this.selectedMeridiem);
    },

    //Get the input field's time
    getText: function(input) {
      return $(input.target).val();
    }


  });

  //Create timepickers
  $.fn.timepicker = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      new Timepicker(this, options);
    });
  };

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" name="event-start-time" id="event-start-time" class="form-input timepicker grid-5" />
  <input type="text" name="event-end-time" id="event-end-time" class="form-input timepicker grid-5" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.timepicker').timepicker({});
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does it still do it if you change it to `$('.timepicker').timepicker();` ? You are passing in an empty array not an object. Not sure if it matters, but it's strange none the less.

Comment: Sorry, in my actual code it has an empty object. It only represents a possible list of future options. In other words yes it still does it.

Comment: "*`//Create only one timepicker per page`*" is not exactly like allowing multiple instances. All your `Timepicker` instances reference the same DOM element. Is that expected?

Comment: @Bergi When I say a single timepicker I mean that I only want one to generate a single picker that multiple inputs can use. Kind of like how you can use the same jQuery UI datepicker calendar on multiple inputs

Comment: @EricGagnon: Yes, but your `TimePicker`s all do attach their event handlers on the same DOM element, and so one event affects all inputs. You'll need to have a static variable that tells *whether and on which input* the timepicker is currently active.

Comment: @Bergi I see what you mean. Do you have any suggestions about how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by removing the previous up and down event click event handlers and then reapplying the new click event handlers.  This was accomplished by changing

```
$(this.up).on('click', $.proxy(this.changeValue, this, '+', element));
$(this.down).on('click', $.proxy(this.changeValue, this, '-', element));
```

to

```
$(this.up).off('click').on('click', $.proxy(this.changeValue, this, '+', element));

$(this.down).off('click').on('click', $.proxy(this.changeValue, this, '-', element));
```

Thanks for all the advice!